# A question about digital transmission from a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

For a half km digital transmission I want to use RS485 protocol. I want to sample an analog voltage by an uC like arduino and send this data digitally for half km to a receiver. I want to poll/retrieve the data by sending a character to the uC via the RS485 protocol. So for instance if I send character 'D' it I will receive data. This is to synchronize with the other com port inputs.

But the uCs dont have RS485 interfaces.

My questions are:

1-) Is RS485 a good choice for such long distance?

2-) First thing came to my mind was a TTL to RS485 converter. Does anyone have experience with that? Or is there simpler or better way?

**edit:**

I might need more than 5 of this setup and I want to receive the data synchronous at the PC end. So not a single port. I'm not experienced whether a wireless or wired digital protocol suits more for this. Would polling data solve the synchronization latency issues?

Comment: Maybe it's worthwhile also to check for wireless transmission methods, that would save about half kilometer of wiring.

Comment: I couldn't find an RF module with such range.

Comment: @newage2000 LoRa and even BLE 5.0 long range should work

Comment: @pipe I might need 5 or more of this setup and be sure the data is synchronous thats why I want to poll the data. But regarding your comment, how about at the receiver side, I need another uC to send the data to the PC?

Comment: @newage2000 I'm not sure, probably not, but that's a completely different question. I think it's better to keep this question about RS485, and alternatives. Maybe you can update your question with the synchronous requirement, makes it easier for someone to give advice. BLE has lousy and random latency.

Comment: okay i made an edit

Comment: [RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) "can be used with .... distances up to 1,200m"

Comment: I want the data coming from the sensors be synchrone. Isn't RS485 asynchrone? There is no dedicated clock. If I use RS485 via modbus RTU upto 20 sensors would the incoming data be synchronous?

Answer (score 2):

RS-485 is easily controlled using a MCU UART plus an extra pin to control the data direction. Generally you would add a driver (the SN75176 is the grand-daddy but  there are many others) and it would be prudent to add ESD protection.

Galvanic isolation may be a good idea for such a long run. You need to consider things like current induced by nearby lightning and the fairly narrow common mode range of the differential receiver. Needless to say it needs to be properly terminated and you may be limited in data rate by the long run.

You can get an RS-485 to USB adapter for a PC but you must avoid cheap ones that do not properly drive the bus differentially. Some of them are quite appalling - they only drive the bus in one direction to avoid having to deal with data direction. Fine for a few meters if there is no EMI, maybe.

You might want to look at alternatives such as fiber optic cable or wireless if this is a serious application.

Comment: But I want the data coming from the sensors be synchrone. Isn't RS485 asynchrone? There is no dedicated clock. If I use RS485 via modbus RTU upto 20 sensors would the incoming data be synchronous?

Comment: @newage2000 RS-485 is an *electrical* specification (just as RS-232). You have to run another protocol on top of that. If you are using an UART (which is the norm for serial ports), they indeed run asynchronously and rely on the clocks on both ends to be sufficiently accurate.

Comment: @CL how can I be sure that the sensors do send the data almost at the same time in the data they send do not include time stamp? Is the only way to send data with time stamp?

Comment: Do the sensors have a clock? Don't they just react to the master's commands?

Comment: You could poll the sensors from a master.

Comment: Yes but polling takes minimum 20ms in Modbus. And normally around 100ms. For 30 sensors this corresponds at least 3 seconds of delay. If the sensors does not provide timestamps, is there a workaround to sync? And I cannot increase baudrate too much because the lenght is 500 meters

Comment: What's your target synchronization error? You could consider a broadcast sync to trigger data acquisition and staggered delays before actually sending the data.

Answer (score 0):

RS-485 is a very good solution in this case (if you can afford the wire).

The part you are looking for is called an "RS-485 transceiver" or "RS-485 driver".

Answer (score 0):

@Newage2000 - You can look at HC-12 module. It has pretty good range. Try using that module at lower baud rates so that you can get long range. I personally using HC-12 module to transmit load values to my receiver at 9600 baud for a distance of 250 mtr.

For synchronization purpose why don't you use **MODBUS RTU** protocol. Its my one of the fav protocol for long distance communication.

Comment: You mean like this one: http://www.icpdas.com/root/product/solutions/remote_io/rs-485/i-7000_m-7000/i-7000_m-7000_introduction.html ?

Comment: Visit this link https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/understanding-and-implementing-the-hc-12-wireless-transceiver-module/

Comment: Did you use HC-12 module for many sensors simultaneously? I need maybe upto 20 and Im afraid wireless protocols will cause issues in synchronization. RS485 Modbus is also asynchronous.

Comment: Yes. You have communication channel option. Can u explain ur system. How many master controller r there and how many slave ??

Comment: Polling between the master and a single slave takes minimum 20ms in Modbus. And normally around 100ms. For 30 sensors this corresponds at least 3 seconds of delay. If the sensors does not provide timestamps, is there a workaround to sync? And I cannot increase baudrate too much because the lenght is 500 meters

Comment: How do you synchronize the incoming data from several sensors?

Comment: First query 1st device and wait for response for x amount time. If u don't receive response then it's time out and move onto next sensor.

Answer (score -1):

@newage2000 : Please loook at the image attached. Hope it gives you the better idea of what i am proposing.
[image]